# MapReduce job doesn't run on complete data

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have dataset(input.csv) containing 35 columns(0-34 positions). If I run my MRv2 program on this then I am getting "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException".

But, if I run the program on snapshot of dataset containing the same columns, then it runs successfully.

**Error**

```
15/07/20 11:05:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1437379028043_0018_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 34
    at lotus.staging.StageMapper.map(StageMapper.java:88)
    at lotus.staging.StageMapper.map(StageMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

**StageMapper**

```
package lotus.staging;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class StageMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] record = value.toString().split(",");

    // Key
    String stg_table = null;

    String report_code = record[0].trim();
    String product_type_description = null;
    String principal_amount = record[1];
    String funded = record[2].trim();
    String facility_id = record[3];
    String loan_id = record[4];

    // Start Date
    String start_date = record[5];

    // Maturity Date
    String end_date = record[6];

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
    long diff;
    long diffDays = 0l;

    try {
        startDate = df.parse(start_date);
        endDate = df.parse(end_date);
        df.format(startDate);
        df.format(endDate);
        diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Date Diff
    String date_diff = String.valueOf(diffDays);

    String next_reset_date = record[7];
    String interest_rate = record[8];
    String base_interest_rate = record[9];
    String counterparty_industry_id = record[10];
    String industry_name = record[11];
    String counterparty_id = record[12];
    String counterparty_name = record[13];

    // Bank Number
    String vehicle_code = record[14];

    String vehicle_description = record[15];

    // Branch Number
    String cost_center_code = record[16];

    String branch_borrower_name = record[17];
    String igl_code = record[20];

    // Participation Bal Begin Month
    String participated_amt = record[21];

    String sys_id = record[23];

    // Loan To Value
    String ltv = record[26];

    String accrual_status = record[27];
    String country_code = record[30];
    String fiscal_year = record[31];
    String accounting_period = record[32];
    String accounting_day = record[33];
    String control_category = record[34];

    // CONTROL_CATEGORY_DESC, Secred_BY_Re

    if (report_code.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        product_type_description = "Commercial_Loan";
        stg_table = "stg_lon";
    } else if (report_code.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
        product_type_description = "Mortgage_Loan";
        stg_table = "stg_mgt";
    } else if (report_code.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
        product_type_description = "Installment_Loan";
        stg_table = "stg_lon";
    } else if (report_code.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
        product_type_description = "Revolving Credit";
        stg_table = "stg_lon";
    }

    // Value
    String data = report_code + "," + product_type_description + ","
            + principal_amount + "," + funded + "," + facility_id + ","
            + loan_id + "," + start_date + "," + end_date + "," + date_diff
            + "," + next_reset_date + "," + interest_rate + ","
            + base_interest_rate + "," + counterparty_industry_id + ","
            + industry_name + "," + counterparty_id + ","
            + counterparty_name + "," + vehicle_code + ","
            + vehicle_description + "," + cost_center_code + ","
            + branch_borrower_name + "," + igl_code + ","
            + participated_amt + "," + sys_id + "," + ltv + ","
            + accrual_status + "," + country_code + "," + fiscal_year + ","
            + accounting_period + "," + accounting_day + ","
            + control_category;

    context.write(new Text(stg_table), new Text(data));

} // map() ends
} // Mapper ends
```

**StageReducer**

```
package lotus.staging;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

public class StageReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private MultipleOutputs mos;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (Text value : values) {
            mos.write(key, value, key.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        mos.close();
    }
}
```

**StageDriver**

```
package lotus.staging;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class StageDriver {
    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "StageDriver");

        // conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
        // conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
        //conf.set("mapreduce.output.key.field.separator", ",");

        job.setJarByClass(StageDriver.class);
        LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);


        // Mapper and Mapper-Output Key
        job.setMapperClass(StageMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.set("mapred.max.split.size", "1020");


        // Reducer and Output Key and Value
        job.setReducerClass(StageReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // Input parameters to execute
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        // deleting the output path automatically from hdfs so that we don't
        // have delete it explicitly

        // outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

        // exiting the job only if the flag value becomes false

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

Below are the datasets

[Snapshot-Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HO4iQfItyeUmZ5SFNxQ0RyaU0/view?usp=sharing) [Complete-Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HO4iQfItyecktEa1ZQVEVQZVE/view?usp=sharing)

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the rows in the input.csv is incomplete or has a formatting error (improperly escaped). Try to figure out which row it is. You can catch an exception where this error occurs and print out the row number and fix your data.

```
try {
CODE WHERE THE OUTOFBOUNDS HAPPENS
}
catch (Exception e) {

    LOG.warn(String.format("Invalid data in row: %d", row));
    System.out.println(String.format("Invalid data in row: %d", row));


}
```

So in your case that means:

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] record = value.toString().split(",");

    // Key
    String stg_table = null;
try{
    String report_code = record[0].trim();
    String product_type_description = null;
    String principal_amount = record[1];
    String funded = record[2].trim();
    String facility_id = record[3];
    String loan_id = record[4];

    // Start Date
    String start_date = record[5];

    // Maturity Date
    String end_date = record[6];



DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
long diff;
long diffDays = 0l;

try {
    startDate = df.parse(start_date);
    endDate = df.parse(end_date);
    df.format(startDate);
    df.format(endDate);
    diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Date Diff
String date_diff = String.valueOf(diffDays);

String next_reset_date = record[7];
String interest_rate = record[8];
String base_interest_rate = record[9];
String counterparty_industry_id = record[10];
String industry_name = record[11];
String counterparty_id = record[12];
String counterparty_name = record[13];

// Bank Number
String vehicle_code = record[14];

String vehicle_description = record[15];

// Branch Number
String cost_center_code = record[16];

String branch_borrower_name = record[17];
String igl_code = record[20];

// Participation Bal Begin Month
String participated_amt = record[21];

String sys_id = record[23];

// Loan To Value
String ltv = record[26];

String accrual_status = record[27];
String country_code = record[30];
String fiscal_year = record[31];
String accounting_period = record[32];
String accounting_day = record[33];
String control_category = record[34];

}
    catch (Exception e) {
if {record.size() > 0} {
    // LOG.warn(String.format("Invalid data in row: %s", record[0].trim()));
    System.out.println(String.format("Invalid data in record id: %s", record[0].trim()));}
else{
System.out.println("Empty Record Found");
}
    return void;
}
...
```

I'm using the record id, because you don't have a row number, but then you can search your that for that record id. And presumably there is at least a first entry in your record. Otherwise you can also check to see if the record is empty.

Comment: you should give the traceback to know where exactly the outof bounds happens. That's where you want to handle the exception.

Comment: also added a return void so that it skips the record in case of an error and goes to the next.

Comment: btw if you could also accept the java tag, that would make the code much more readible because stackoverflow will know that the code is in java.

Comment: Do I need to give 

System.out.println(String.format("Invalid data in record id: %s", record[0].trim()));

for every record(record[0] till record[34])?

Comment: No.
I assume you can identify the record with record[0], so that is all that you need.

Comment: using record[34] would defeat the purpose because it would give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException again.

Comment: Actually I checked for it and I resolved Null Pointer Exception. But still I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

Comment: At which line of code? At this line: `    System.out.println(String.format("Invalid data in record id: %s", record[0].trim()));`? Then that means  you have an empy record ... You can check for it explicitly, I will modify the answer to take that possibilty into account.

Comment: In 1 line - i have some columns with no data.

Comment: there you go. that is what causes the problem. you need to fix or remove the lines in your input with missing data.

Comment: sorry I just realized that in the code i put above, I didn't encapsulate all the record[] lines in the `try{}`. all the accesses to the record array must be inside the try because otherwise they will fail where the record is incomplete.